# Django - Avoiding joins when querying foreign key ids?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-queryset

Say I have a simple blog entry model in Django:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    entry = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
```

Now say I want to query for a author or topic, but exclude a particular topic altogether.

```
entry_list = Entry.objects.filter(Q(author=12)|Q(topic=123)).exclude(topic=666)
```

Sinmple enough, but I've found that this raw SQL contains a join on the topic table, even though it doesn't have to be used:

```
SELECT `blog_entry`.`id`
FROM `blog_entry`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `blog_topic`
    ON (`blog_entry`.`topic_id` = `blog_topic`.`id`)
WHERE ((`blog_entry`.`author_id` = 12  
        OR `blog_entry`.`topic_id` = 123 
       ) 
       AND NOT ((`blog_topic`.`id` = 666
                  AND NOT (`blog_topic`.`id` IS NULL)
                  AND `blog_topic`.`id` IS NOT NULL
                ))
      )
```

Why is that? How can I get Django to query only the column ids and not join tables? I've tried the following but it give a FieldError:

```
entry_list = Entry.objects.filter(Q(author_id=12)|Q(topic_id=123)).exclude(topic_id=666)
```

Answer (score 2):

i wonder whether this is a bug.

trying a similar example, i get no join when putting the `exclude` before the `filter` (but i do get it using your order)

Comment: Agreed, I get the same thing you as you, is there any way you can force it to just use the column_id?